# How to tag an element and use this tag or id later

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a website and currently, I will display a `Card element` for any topics I am pulling from the BE.

The BE will send me a Json with id, title, description of each element and for each element I will render a card defined like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import BlueButton from '../materialdesign/BlueButton'
import TextContents from '../../assets/translations/TextContents';

class ClassCard extends React.Component {  

    render() {
        return(
            <div style={tileStyle}>
                
                <img
                    src= { this.props.pic }
                    style= { tileStyle }
                    alt="Village"
                />

                <p style={titleStyle}>{this.props.title}</p>
                <p style={descStyle}>{this.props.desc}</p>
                <div style = {btnStyle}>
                <BlueButton textSize="18" link_href="/" text={TextContents.BookBtn} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ClassCard;
```

For now, I am calling the class as below:

```
        <div>
            <h2> Test Categories </h2>
            <ClassCard title={title1} desc={desc1} pic={Salad} id='123456789'></ClassCard>

        </div>
```

`id` is hard coded for now in order to test it but later it will be replaced by the id pull from the JSON.

What I am looking to do is to pass this id to the `ClassCard` and then when I click on the Button defined in the `ClassCard` it redirects you to something like `href='/details?id='123456789'`.

Then when the `details` page open, I extract the param `id` and get the number and can pull the data of this specific id

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can listen onClick event and then you can set `window.location.href` for the redirect.

```
handleOnClick(e) {
   window.location.href = `/details?id=${this.props.id}`  // redirect to /details?id=123456789
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a prop!
In your card, just add this into the href.

```
import React from 'react';
import BlueButton from '../materialdesign/BlueButton'
import TextContents from '../../assets/translations/TextContents';

class ClassCard extends React.Component {  

    render() {
        return(
            <div style={tileStyle}>
                
                <img
                    src= { this.props.pic }
                    style= { tileStyle }
                    alt="Village"
                />

                <p style={titleStyle}>{this.props.title}</p>
                <p style={descStyle}>{this.props.desc}</p>
                <div style = {btnStyle}>
                <BlueButton textSize="18" link_href={`/details?id=${this.props.id}`} text={TextContents.BookBtn} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ClassCard;
```

This is grabbing the id, and creating the string that you wanted, Assuming the button component handles it.

Then pass the id's into the card, as you were:

```
<div>
  <h2> Test Categories </h2>
  <ClassCard title={title1} desc={desc1} pic={Salad} id='123456789'></ClassCard>
</div>
```